# Field redefinition of gauge fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, field-theory, yang-mills

Let us consider the non-abelian gauge theory $SU(3)_c \times SU(3)$ where the groups are treated as different but the couplings are taken equal. Let us suppose we have a mixing term among the field-strenghts
$$
\frac{1}{4g^2} F^a_{\mu\nu} F^{a,\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{4g^2}G_{a,\mu\nu}G^{a,\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{4g_p^2}F_{\mu\nu}G^{\mu\nu}
$$
where $g_p \neq g$.

I want to diagonalize the kinetic term **only** by field redefinition. 
For example, the following transformation drops the mixing out
$$
F_{\mu\nu}^a \rightarrow F_{\mu\nu}^a - \frac{1}{2}\frac{g^2}{g_p^2}G_{\mu\nu}^a 
$$
$$
G_{\mu\nu}^a \rightarrow G_{\mu\nu}^a 
$$

How can I find the corresponding field redefinition on the gauge fields $G_\mu^a$ and $F_\mu^a$?

Comment: You are aware that your mixed term is not invariant under your group, right?

Comment: @CosmasZachos This is a 3-years old question. Now it is clear to me that the mixing term is not invariant under $SU(3)\times SU(3)$ but who knows what I had in mind. Maybe the mixing term was explicitly breaking the group to the diagonal one - boh.

Answer (score 0):

The actual transformation will be the same as for the field strength, since the transformation
$$
A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} + B_{\mu}
$$
automatically implies
$$
F_{\mu\nu}^{A} \to F_{\mu\nu}^{A} + F_{\mu\nu}^{B}
$$

Comment: I have a doubt. The field F and G transform differently. I knew that field redefinitions are allowed only if they are consistent with the symmetries. The transformation I wrote would spoil gauge symmetry, doesn't?

Comment: @apt45 : This is simply not the gauge transformation, this is the field redefinition. As long as you don't have the mass term, for one of the fields, the lagrangian after the replacement will be explicitly gauge invariant.

Comment: I know this is a field redefinition. I am just saying that my field redefinition does not preserve the gauge transformation property of the original fields. Am I correct?

Comment: @apt45 : the transformation you use should be interpreted as the new field $A_{\mu}' = A_{\mu} +B_{\mu}, B_{\mu}' = B_{\mu}$ definition, which naturally appears when you expand all the kinetic terms in the initial lagrangian and note that in terms of $A_{\mu}',B_{\mu}'$ the kinetic term is diagonal. Real problem, as I've noted in my previous comment, appears if one field, say, $A_{\mu}$, is the true gauge field, while another one is massive.